# finding conditions for certain limits of integrals...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

let $g$ continuous on $[0,1]$. find conditions on function $g$ that are equivalent to $lim_{n \to \infty} ||g^nf||_{2}=0$ for all $f$ in $L^2(0,1)$

we are completely stuck on this one. Tried some obvious things like making $g$ $L^2$ or bounded by 1. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $g$ is such that $\lVert g^nf\rVert_2\to 0$ for each $f\in L^2(0,1)$. In particular, with $f=1$, we obtain that for a subsequence, $|g^{n_k}|\to 0$ almost everywhere. We thus have $|g|\lt 1$ almost everywhere or equivalently, $\lambda\{|g|\geqslant 1\}=0$.

Conversely, assume that $\lambda\{|g|\geqslant 1\}=0$. Then we obtain $\lVert g^nf\rVert_2\to 0$ for each $f\in L^2(0,1)$ using dominated convergence.